# Database: Progress bar with result from SUM

Tags: database, progress-bar, sum

I have a progessbar which shows the value in percent from my database. I have a column named score and a row with a value of 50. The progress bar is now half full. When i add a new row with 50 i want the progress bar to be full, but that does not work.(It blows the scale and becomes about 2000%)  Is there a way to change this query so the sum of the whole score-column will be counted in the progress bar? `$query = "select * from poeng";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT SUM(score) AS score FROM poeng"
```

should do it.